# Ruby on rails How can i implement search bar feature to find other user by username?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to implement a search bar feature in my rails app, to find other users by username or full_name, i, 'm using devise gem for the users, I dont't have any users_controllers just I have a user.rb model? Any help and thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Fazaa! This question seems a bit general. I was able to do a quick google search and found this: https://medium.com/@yassimortensen/simple-search-form-in-rails-8483739e4042 which I'm sure if you followed and adapted to use the model/column you want to search by you could very well use in your project. You hinted at it but yes you'll probably want some kind of users controller or a user search controller and a class method in your model to search by username or full_name

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create a controller. To create controller run below command.

```
rails g controller search
```

This command will create a file in your app/controller/search_controller.rb go this file and add below code.

```
def search_user 
    @get_user = User.where("username LIKE ? AND full_name LIKE ?","#{params[:username]}%", "#{params[:full_name]}%" )
    puts @get_user
end
```

**NOTE:-** One thing you have to remember that User table column name and entered name should be right.

Now next step to set route in config/route.rb file

```
get '/search_user', to: 'search/search_user'
```

Next step call **search_user** from html.erb file.

```
<%= form_with url: "/search_user", method: :get do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :username %>
  <%= form.text_field :full_name %>
  <%= form.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```